# Como adicionar um alias 'AS' em um comando PIVOT com colunas dinâmicas?

Tags: sql-server, tsql

```
-- Apaga a tabela temporária se ela existir
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Sales
GO

-- Cria tabela temporária com dados de exemplo
CREATE TABLE #Sales
(
    [Product] VARCHAR(50),
    [Month]   INT,
    [Revenue] MONEY
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Sales
VALUES ('Product A', 1, 1000),
       ('Product A', 2, 1500),
       ('Product B', 1, 2000),
       ('Product B', 3, 2500),
       ('Product C', 2, 3000),
       ('Product C', 3, 3500),
       ('Product D', 4, 999)
GO


-- Cria a consulta usando PIVOT dinâmica
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Month])
                      FROM #Sales
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')


-- Seta a consulta dinâmica
SET @query = '

SELECT [Product]
     , ' + @cols + '
FROM (SELECT [Product]
           , [Month]
           , [Revenue]
      FROM #Sales) x
         PIVOT
         (
         SUM([Revenue])
         FOR [Month] IN (' + @cols + ')
         ) p

'

--  Executa a consulta dinâmica armazenada na @query
EXECUTE (@query)
```

Não sei quantos meses serão retornados, mas o objetivo é dar apelidos às colunas correspondentes aos meses.

```
Product     |JAN        |FEV        |MAR        |ABR
---------------------------------------------------------
Product A   |1000.0000  |1500.0000  |NULL       |
Product B   |2000.0000  |NULL       |2500.0000  |
Product C   |NULL       |3000.0000  |3500.0000  |
Product D   |NULL       |NULL       |NULL       |999.0000
```

Answer (score -2):

Para o exemplo dado, a maneira mais simples de resolver isso seria

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Sales
GO

CREATE TABLE #Sales
(
    [Product] VARCHAR(50),
    [Month]   INT,
    [Revenue] MONEY
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Sales
VALUES ('Product A', 1, 1000),
       ('Product A', 2, 1500),
       ('Product B', 1, 2000),
       ('Product B', 3, 2500),
       ('Product C', 2, 3000),
       ('Product C', 3, 3500),
       ('Product D', 4, 999),
       ('Product D', 5, 88)
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MonthNames
CREATE TABLE #MonthNames
(
    [Month] INT,
    [MonthName] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #MonthNames
VALUES (1, 'Jan'),
       (2, 'Fev'),
       (3, 'Mar'),
       (4, 'Abr'),
       (5, 'Mai'),
       (6, 'Jun'),
       (7, 'Jul'),
       (8, 'Ago'),
       (9, 'Set'),
       (10, 'Out'),
       (11, 'Nov'),
       (12, 'Dez')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols_with_alias AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Month])
                      FROM #Sales
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

--Criando a nova variável com os aliases personalizados
SELECT @cols_with_alias = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + QUOTENAME(m.[Month]) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(m.[MonthName])
                      FROM #Sales s
                      JOIN #MonthNames m ON s.[Month] = m.[Month]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')

SET @query = '

SELECT [Product]
     , ' + @cols_with_alias + '
FROM (SELECT [Product]
           , [Month]
           , [Revenue]
      FROM #Sales) x
         PIVOT
         (
         SUM([Revenue])
         FOR [Month] IN (' + @cols + ')
         ) p

'

EXECUTE (@query)
```